# How to overload operator =

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the assignment operator as a member function to take a string as an argument and assigns its value to `A`, the current object.  I posted the errors in the comments below.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it has something to do with the parameters, and probably the code inside the definition.

I am not sure if I declared it correctly, but I declared it like this:

```
WORD operator=(const string& other);
```

And I defined it like this:

```
WORD WORD::operator=(const string& other) //<---not sure if I did the parameters Correctly
{
(*this) = other;
return (*this);
}
```

Here is the entire file if it helps:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma once

class alpha_numeric //node
{
   public:
char symbol; //data in node
alpha_numeric *next;//points to next node
};

class WORD
{
   public:
      WORD() : front(0) {length=0;}; //front of list initially set to Null
      WORD(const WORD& other);
      bool IsEmpty();
      int Length();
      void Insert(WORD bword, int position);
      WORD operator=(const string& other); 

   private:
      alpha_numeric *front; //points to the front node of a list
      int length;
};

WORD WORD::operator=(const string& other) //<---not sure if I did the parameters Correctly
{
      (*this) = other;
      return (*this);
}
```

Comment: Please do post the "unreadable mess".

Comment: Error 3 error LNK2005: "public: class WORD __thiscall WORD::operator=(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??4WORD@@QAE?AV0@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) already defined in word.obj C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\School Programs\Data Structures Assignment 2\Data Structures Assignment 2\word_driver.obj

Comment: Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall WORD::WORD(class WORD const &)" (??0WORD@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "public: class WORD __thiscall WORD::operator=(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??4WORD@@QAE?AV0@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\School Programs\Data Structures Assignment 2\Data Structures Assignment 2\word.obj

Comment: Error 5 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall WORD::WORD(class WORD const &)" (??0WORD@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\School Programs\Data Structures Assignment 2\Data Structures Assignment 2\word_driver.obj

Comment: Error 6 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\School Programs\Data Structures Assignment 2\Debug\Data Structures Assignment 2.exe

Comment: Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: The first error is telling you that you have the function defined in multiple compilation units (word.cpp and word_driver.cpp) -- probably due to having it in a header file.

Comment: The remaining error are telling you that you have no definition of the constructor WORD::WORD anywhere, just the declaration in the header file.

Comment: public: __thiscall WORD::WORD(class WORD const &) => that's the missing definition of the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok 2 things:

First you are missing the definition of your copy constructor, so that's not compiling.
Try this inside your class (only partial implementation shown):

```
WORD(const WORD& other)
: length(other.length)
{
    // Construct me !
}
```

Second, your assignment operator is correct, but recursive on all control path. E.g. it calls itself indefinitely. Your probably want to assign members inside the method (again, only partial implementation shown):

```
WORD WORD::operator=(const string& other)
{
    // Only copy the length, the rest is to be filled
    this.length = other.length;
    return (*this);
}
```

Lastly, as others have pointed out, you have multiple definitions of the same symbols inside your executable. To fix that you will have to make sure your header is included only once (the #pragma once should take care of that) but also move all implementation details off the header file to the source file. e.g. move the definition of WORD WORD::operator=(const string& other) to the CPP file.

Comment: So if I do this, is this saying that the length of letters in A will now be the same length of letters in the string?  If so, Will that also make A = whatever the string was?

Comment: Partially, it will only copy the length member. You will need to implement the copying of other members, such as the front. For example if you want to do a shallow copy (only copy the pointer) you do: this.front = other.front;. Note that this will not make a true copy. For that you will need to make a deep copy of the alpha_numeric class.

Comment: That's correct, but it will make sure the header is included only once, however without seeing each CPP file content, it is hard to tell why there are duplicate symbols.

Comment: No, the pragma won't change anything. If the header was being included multiple times the code wouldn't have compiled, so wouldn't get as far as a linker error.  It's not hard to see why there are duplicate symbols, it's because there's a non-inline function definition in a header.

Comment: There are duplicate definitions because it's defined in a header included from multiple source files, and isn't declared `inline`. To fix that, either declare it `inline`, or move the definition inside the class definition, or move it into a source file.

Comment: I edited the answer to better reflect what has been said in the comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is from the linker; it's telling you that it's found multiple definitions of the same function.  This is because you've defined the function in the header file, which has been included into multiple source files, therefore you've ended up with multiple definitions of the function.

Comment: The multiple definitions can be solved by either moving the definition of the function to a source file, or making the definition `inline` (but only do one of those, not both!)